# How can I create a Segue from UICollectionView Cell?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a UICollectionView made of Cells of the size of my screen (yes that's a lot of 'of').

I would like to make a segue to another view when I click on a button of one of the cell. I created the segue with an identifier in my storyboard but can't figure how to perform it programmaticaly.

Thank you

Comment: I tried to do
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showResult" sender:self];

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just found where was my error, I was performing the segue on my collectionview Cell instead of my collectionView !

Here is the code
       [self.collectionView performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showResult" sender:self];